# Setting two TikZ pictures next to each other

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, combine

I have two TikZ pictures and I want to set them beside each other such that each one has its own caption. I attempted to use \hfil but it created a big gap between them. Also, my thesis set up to have 4cm (left margin), so it is a bit challenging to set them together with a suitable size though I used \resizebox. Can any help me to fix it?

```
             \documentclass[10pt]{article}
              \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
               \usepackage{mathrsfs}
               \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
                \pagestyle{empty}
                 \begin{document}
                 \definecolor{xdxdff}{rgb}{0.49019607843137253,0.49019607843137253,1.}
               \definecolor{ududff}{rgb}{0.30196078431372547,0.30196078431372547,1.}
                \definecolor{zzttqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,0.}\definecolor{zzttqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,0.}

                  \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
             \clip(-4.3,-7.36) rectangle (20.1,6.3);
             \fill[line width=0.8pt,color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (0.,5.) -- (1.24,5.) -- (1.2201234230270745,0.19579267785163076) -- (0.,0.2) -- cycle;
             \fill[line width=0.8pt,color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (4.64,5.) -- (5.8,5.) -- (5.8,0.18) -- (4.64015172233386,0.1839994768195382) -- cycle;
            \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,5.)-- (5.8,5.);
            \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,4.)-- (5.8,4.);
            \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,0.2)-- (5.8,0.18);
            \draw (0.2,0.3) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize L_{f}$};
            \draw (4.7,0.26) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize L_{a}=L_{e}$};
            \draw [line width=0.8pt] (4.64,5.)-- (4.64015172233386,0.1839994768195382);
             \draw [line width=0.8pt] (5.8,1.18)-- (0.,1.16);
           \draw [line width=0.8pt] (1.24,5.)-- (1.2201234230270745,0.19579267785163076);
            \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,5.)-- (0.,0.2);
            \draw [line width=0.8pt] (5.8,5.)-- (5.8,0.18);
             \draw (0.62,4.76) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize h$};
             \draw (4.7,4.76) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize ha$};
             \draw (2.4,5.16) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize \psi_{a}\vert_{_{_{H_{f}}}}   $};
             \draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.04,4.3)-- (4.42,4.28);
             \draw [line width=1.2pt] (5.5,4.2)-- (5.5,1.38);
            \draw (4.68,3.34) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize \phi_{a^{*}}\vert_{_{_{H_{a}}}}   $};
               \draw (2.3,2.84) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize \Psi   $};
              \draw (4.74,1.28) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize a^{*}ha$};
             \draw (0.06,5.18) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize H_{f}$};
            \draw (5.32,5.18) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize H_{a}$};
            \draw (5.26,0.86) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize H_{e}$};
            \draw (-0.72,1.08) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize R_{e}$};
            \draw [line width=0.8pt,dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (1.42,3.78)-- (4.42,1.36);
            \begin{scriptsize}
             \draw [fill=black,shift={(4.42,4.28)},rotate=270] (0,0) ++(0 pt,2.25pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,-3.375pt)--++(-3.8971143170299736pt,0 pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,3.375pt);
              \draw [fill=black,shift={(5.5,1.38)},rotate=180] (0,0) ++(0 pt,2.25pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,-3.375pt)--++(-3.8971143170299736pt,0 pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,3.375pt);
                \draw [fill=ududff] (1.04,4.3) circle (1.0pt);
               \draw [fill=ududff] (5.5,4.2) circle (1.0pt);
                \draw [fill=black,shift={(4.42,1.36)}] (0,0) ++(0 pt,2.25pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,-3.375pt)--++(-3.8971143170299736pt,0 pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,3.375pt);
             \draw [fill=xdxdff] (-5.8,5.) circle (2.5pt);
              \draw[color=xdxdff] (-4.18,6.47) node {$G'$};
              \end{scriptsize}
              \end{tikzpicture}
              \hfil
                \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
               \clip(-4.3,-7.36) rectangle (20.1,6.3);
               \fill[line width=2.pt,color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (0.,5.) -- (5.8,5.) -- (5.8,4.) -- (0.,4.) -- cycle;
              \fill[line width=2.pt,color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (0.,1.16) -- (5.8,1.18) -- (5.8,0.18) -- (0.,0.2) -- cycle;
              \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,5.)-- (5.8,5.);
              \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,4.)-- (5.8,4.);
              \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,0.2)-- (5.8,0.18);
              \draw (-0.66,5.02) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize R_{f}$};
               \draw (4.7,0.26) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize L_{a}=L_{e}$};
               \draw [line width=0.8pt] (4.64,5.)-- (4.64015172233386,0.1839994768195382);
                \draw [line width=0.8pt] (5.8,1.18)-- (0.,1.16);
                \draw [line width=0.8pt] (1.24,5.)-- (1.2201234230270745,0.19579267785163076);
               \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,5.)-- (0.,0.2);
               \draw [line width=0.8pt] (5.8,5.)-- (5.8,0.18);
               \draw (2.2,2.76) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize \Psi^{-1}   $};
               \draw (0.06,5.18) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize H_{f}$};
               \draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (4.74,0.44)-- (1.42,0.44);
                \draw [line width=0.8pt,dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (0.18,0.66)-- (0.2,3.8);
                \draw (2.66,1.3) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize \psi_{a^{*}}\vert_{_{_{H_{e}}}}   $};
                \draw (5.32,1.32) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize H_{e}$};
                \draw (0.38,3.32) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize \phi_{a}\vert_{_{_{H_{a^{*}}}}}   $};
                \draw (-0.72,1.08) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize R_{a^{*}}$};
               \draw (4.86,0.96) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize g$};
                \draw [line width=0.8pt,dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (1.42,3.78)-- (4.42,1.36);
                 \draw (0.4,0.94) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize ga^{*}$};
                   \draw (0.28,4.72) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize aga^{*}$};
                   \draw (0.62,1.38) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize H_{a^{*}}$};
               \begin{scriptsize}
                \draw [fill=black] (4.74,0.44) circle (1.0pt);
                \draw [fill=black,shift={(1.42,0.44)},rotate=90] (0,0) ++(0 pt,2.25pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,-3.375pt)--++(-3.8971143170299736pt,0 pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,3.375pt);
                 \draw [fill=black] (0.18,0.66) circle (1.0pt);
                  \draw [fill=black,shift={(0.2,3.8)}] (0,0) ++(0 pt,2.25pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,-3.375pt)--++(-3.8971143170299736pt,0 pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,3.375pt);
                  \draw [fill=black,shift={(1.42,3.78)},rotate=180] (0,0) ++(0 pt,2.25pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,-3.375pt)--++(-3.8971143170299736pt,0 pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,3.375pt);
                   \end{scriptsize}
                    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please don't get mad at me, but frankly, your figures are a bit ... let's say "unusual". Do you really think you do anyone a favor by jamming stuff up on a small area. A proposal similar to the one by AndréC but with some very modest attempts to clean up, and with captions.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows} % consider using arrows.meta instead
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{xdxdff}{rgb}{0.49019607843137253,0.49019607843137253,1.}
\definecolor{ududff}{rgb}{0.30196078431372547,0.30196078431372547,1.}
\definecolor{zzttqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,0.}\definecolor{zzttqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,0.}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=left box]
  \fill[line width=0.8pt,color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (0.,5.) -- (1.24,5.) -- (1.2201234230270745,0.19579267785163076) -- (0.,0.2) -- cycle;
  \fill[line width=0.8pt,color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (4.64,5.) -- (5.8,5.) -- (5.8,0.18) -- (4.64015172233386,0.1839994768195382) -- cycle;
  \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,5.)-- (5.8,5.);
  \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,4.)-- (5.8,4.);
  \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,0.2)-- (5.8,0.18);
  \draw (0.2,0.3) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle L_{f}$};
  \draw (4.7,0.26) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle L_{a}=L_{e}$};
  \draw [line width=0.8pt] (4.64,5.)-- (4.64015172233386,0.1839994768195382);
  \draw [line width=0.8pt] (5.8,1.18)-- (0.,1.16);
  \draw [line width=0.8pt] (1.24,5.)-- (1.2201234230270745,0.19579267785163076);
  \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,5.)-- (0.,0.2);
  \draw [line width=0.8pt] (5.8,5.)-- (5.8,0.18);
  \draw (0.62,4.76) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle h$};
  \draw (4.7,4.76) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle ha$};
  \draw (2.4,5.16) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle \psi_{a}\vert_{_{_{H_{f}}}}   $};
  \draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.04,4.3)-- (4.42,4.28);
  \draw [line width=1.2pt] (5.5,4.2)-- (5.5,1.38);
  \draw (4.68,3.34) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle \phi_{a^{*}}\vert_{_{_{H_{a}}}}   $};
  \draw (2.3,2.84) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle \Psi   $};
  \draw (4.74,1.28) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle a^{*}ha$};
  \draw (0.06,5.18) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle H_{f}$};
  \draw (5.32,5.18) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle H_{a}$};
  \draw (5.26,0.86) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle H_{e}$};
  \draw (-0.72,1.08) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle R_{e}$};
  \draw [line width=0.8pt,dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (1.42,3.78)-- (4.42,1.36);
  \begin{scope}[font=\scriptsize]
   \draw [fill=black,shift={(4.42,4.28)},rotate=270] (0,0) ++(0 pt,2.25pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,-3.375pt)--++(-3.8971143170299736pt,0 pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,3.375pt);
   \draw [fill=black,shift={(5.5,1.38)},rotate=180] (0,0) ++(0 pt,2.25pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,-3.375pt)--++(-3.8971143170299736pt,0 pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,3.375pt);
   \draw [fill=ududff] (1.04,4.3) circle (1.0pt);
   \draw [fill=ududff] (5.5,4.2) circle (1.0pt);
   \draw [fill=black,shift={(4.42,1.36)}] (0,0) ++(0 pt,2.25pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,-3.375pt)--++(-3.8971143170299736pt,0 pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,3.375pt);
%    \draw [fill=xdxdff] (-5.8,5.) circle (2.5pt);
%    \draw[color=xdxdff] (-4.18,6.47) node {$G'$};
  \end{scope}
 \end{scope}
 \node[anchor=north] at (left box.south){A caption.};
 \begin{scope}[xshift=7.5cm,local bounding box=right box]
  \fill[line width=2.pt,color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (0.,5.) -- (5.8,5.) -- (5.8,4.) -- (0.,4.) -- cycle;
  \fill[line width=2.pt,color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (0.,1.16) -- (5.8,1.18) -- (5.8,0.18) -- (0.,0.2) -- cycle;
  \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,5.)-- (5.8,5.);
  \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,4.)-- (5.8,4.);
  \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,0.2)-- (5.8,0.18);
  \draw (-0.66,5.02) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle R_{f}$};
  \draw (4.7,0.26) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle L_{a}=L_{e}$};
  \draw [line width=0.8pt] (4.64,5.)-- (4.64015172233386,0.1839994768195382);
  \draw [line width=0.8pt] (5.8,1.18)-- (0.,1.16);
  \draw [line width=0.8pt] (1.24,5.)-- (1.2201234230270745,0.19579267785163076);
  \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,5.)-- (0.,0.2);
  \draw [line width=0.8pt] (5.8,5.)-- (5.8,0.18);
  \draw (2.2,2.76) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle \Psi^{-1}   $};
  \draw (0.06,5.18) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle H_{f}$};
  \draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (4.74,0.44)-- (1.42,0.44);
  \draw [line width=0.8pt,dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (0.18,0.66)-- (0.2,3.8);
  \draw (2.66,1.3) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle \psi_{a^{*}}\vert_{_{_{H_{e}}}}   $};
  \draw (5.32,1.32) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle H_{e}$};
  \draw (0.38,3.32) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle \phi_{a}\vert_{_{_{H_{a^{*}}}}}   $};
  \draw (-0.72,1.08) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle R_{a^{*}}$};
  \draw (4.86,0.96) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle g$};
  \draw [line width=0.8pt,dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (1.42,3.78)-- (4.42,1.36);
  \draw (0.4,0.94) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle ga^{*}$};
  \draw (0.28,4.72) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle aga^{*}$};
  \draw (0.62,1.38) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle H_{a^{*}}$};
  \begin{scope}[font=\scriptsize]
   \draw [fill=black] (4.74,0.44) circle (1.0pt);
   \draw [fill=black,shift={(1.42,0.44)},rotate=90] (0,0) ++(0 pt,2.25pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,-3.375pt)--++(-3.8971143170299736pt,0 pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,3.375pt);
   \draw [fill=black] (0.18,0.66) circle (1.0pt);
   \draw [fill=black,shift={(0.2,3.8)}] (0,0) ++(0 pt,2.25pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,-3.375pt)--++(-3.8971143170299736pt,0 pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,3.375pt);
   \draw [fill=black,shift={(1.42,3.78)},rotate=180] (0,0) ++(0 pt,2.25pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,-3.375pt)--++(-3.8971143170299736pt,0 pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,3.375pt);
  \end{scope}
 \end{scope}
 \node[anchor=north] at (right box.south){Another caption.};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Obviously this is still far from optimal. However, at this point it is up to you to clean up.

- What are your `\clip`s good for?
- Since you seem think you help the readers by using tiny fonts: no, not every one likes to use magnifier glasses in order to understand figures. Figures are meant to help people to understand things, not to prevent people from wanting to continue reading.
- Needless to say, but the labels are not at all aligned with the graphical elements.

This is really not to make you mad at me, but I really feel you are using Ti*k*Z not in an optimal way.

To make you a little bit less furious, I translated the left picture to something which is arguably closer to the spirit of Ti*k*Z. (How did you draw your pic? Geocobra? Inkscape?)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,backgrounds,fit}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows} % consider using arrows.meta instead
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{xdxdff}{rgb}{0.49019607843137253,0.49019607843137253,1.}
\definecolor{ududff}{rgb}{0.30196078431372547,0.30196078431372547,1.}
\definecolor{zzttqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,0.}\definecolor{zzttqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,0.}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=left box,line width=0.8pt]
  \node (h) {$h$};  
  \node[above left=1.5pt of h] (Hf) {$H_f$};
  \node[right=4cm of h] (ha) {$h\,a$};  
  \node[above right=1.5pt of ha] (Ha) {$H_{a\vphantom{f}}$};
  \node[below=4cm of ha] (aha) {$a^*\,h\,a$};
  \node[below right=1.5pt of aha] (He) {$H_e$};
  \draw [line width=1.2pt,-latex] (h) -- (ha) 
    node[midway,above]{$\left.\psi_a\right|_{H_f}$};
  \draw [line width=1.2pt,-latex] (ha) -- (aha) 
    node[midway,right]{$\left.\phi_{a^{*}}\right|_{H_{a}}$};
  \draw[line width=0.8pt,dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt,-latex] (h) -- (aha)
   node[midway,above]{$\Psi$};;
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]    
   \node[draw,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.1,fit=(ha) (Ha) (aha) (He)] (fit1){};
   \node[fit=(h) (Hf)] (aux1) {};
   \draw[fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.1] (aux1.north west) rectangle (aux1.east
   |-fit1.south);
   \node[draw,inner sep=0pt,fit=(aux1) (fit1.north east)] (fit2){};
   \node[fit=(aha) (He)] (aux2) {};
   \node[draw,inner sep=0pt,fit=(aux2.north -| aux1.west) (fit1.south east)] (fit3){};
  \end{scope}
  \node[below=2pt of fit1.south] {$L_{a}=L_{e}$};
  \node[below=2pt of aux1|-fit1.south] {$L_{f}$};
  \node[left=2pt of aux1.west|-aux2] {$R_{c}$};
 \end{scope}
 \node[anchor=north] at (left box.south){A caption.};
%  \begin{scope}[shift={([xshift=1cm,yshift=-2cm]left box.east)},local bounding box=right box]
%   \fill[line width=2.pt,color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (0.,5.) -- (5.8,5.) -- (5.8,4.) -- (0.,4.) -- cycle;
%   \fill[line width=2.pt,color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (0.,1.16) -- (5.8,1.18) -- (5.8,0.18) -- (0.,0.2) -- cycle;
%   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,5.)-- (5.8,5.);
%   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,4.)-- (5.8,4.);
%   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,0.2)-- (5.8,0.18);
%   \draw (-0.66,5.02) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle R_{f}$};
%   \draw (4.7,0.26) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle L_{a}=L_{e}$};
%   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (4.64,5.)-- (4.64015172233386,0.1839994768195382);
%   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (5.8,1.18)-- (0.,1.16);
%   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (1.24,5.)-- (1.2201234230270745,0.19579267785163076);
%   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,5.)-- (0.,0.2);
%   \draw [line width=0.8pt] (5.8,5.)-- (5.8,0.18);
%   \draw (2.2,2.76) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle \Psi^{-1}   $};
%   \draw (0.06,5.18) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle H_{f}$};
%   \draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (4.74,0.44)-- (1.42,0.44);
%   \draw [line width=0.8pt,dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (0.18,0.66)-- (0.2,3.8);
%   \draw (2.66,1.3) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle \psi_{a^{*}}\vert_{_{_{H_{e}}}}   $};
%   \draw (5.32,1.32) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle H_{e}$};
%   \draw (0.38,3.32) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle \phi_{a}\vert_{_{_{H_{a^{*}}}}}   $};
%   \draw (-0.72,1.08) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle R_{a^{*}}$};
%   \draw (4.86,0.96) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle g$};
%   \draw [line width=0.8pt,dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (1.42,3.78)-- (4.42,1.36);
%   \draw (0.4,0.94) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle ga^{*}$};
%   \draw (0.28,4.72) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle aga^{*}$};
%   \draw (0.62,1.38) node[anchor=north west] {$\scriptstyle H_{a^{*}}$};
%   \begin{scope}[font=\scriptsize]
%    \draw [fill=black] (4.74,0.44) circle (1.0pt);
%    \draw [fill=black,shift={(1.42,0.44)},rotate=90] (0,0) ++(0 pt,2.25pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,-3.375pt)--++(-3.8971143170299736pt,0 pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,3.375pt);
%    \draw [fill=black] (0.18,0.66) circle (1.0pt);
%    \draw [fill=black,shift={(0.2,3.8)}] (0,0) ++(0 pt,2.25pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,-3.375pt)--++(-3.8971143170299736pt,0 pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,3.375pt);
%    \draw [fill=black,shift={(1.42,3.78)},rotate=180] (0,0) ++(0 pt,2.25pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,-3.375pt)--++(-3.8971143170299736pt,0 pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,3.375pt);
%   \end{scope}
%  \end{scope}
%  \node[anchor=north] at (right box.south){Another caption.};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now you may translate the second picture yourself. When doing it for the first time, this is some effort. However, I'd like to argue that very soon it will pay off as you will be able to make global adjustments with simple switches. You will be much less likely to run in problems which are hard to resolve. And last but not least you will see that, unlike drawing the pictures with some interface, this is real fun.

Comment: +1 But, if you install the showframe package, your figures (like mine in my first answer) exceed the margins.

Comment: @AndréC Thanks and I am aware of this. However, I believe that in their present form the figures are not to be used anywhere, let alone a thesis in which some of the readers assign grades. So I hope the OP cleans up, and then the fine-tuning will make more sense.

Comment: Marmot! Thanks for your suggestions and help but this is the first time I received such a response! from you, though YOU always supported me a lot (this is not the first time by the way). Just imagine how many people, facing a similar issue and seeking an answer, will read it. The labels aligned nicely before I paste them here (I was really shocked when I realized that they appear odd). Anyhow, I will clean it soon and I apologize for any inconvenience caused by my inquiry.

Comment: @MalJA I actually *do* try to support you. You are saying that this is for a thesis, and I just do not want you to run into trouble. And as for the labels: you place them manually, add `\footnotesize` and ignore all the complaints from the compiler. What I did was to replace this by `\scriptstyle`, which is appropriate in math mode, and you see what happens. Main messages: 1. do not use absolute positioning. Ti*k*Z allows you to do much better. 2. Do not jam things up. If you have a figure, try to make at appealing such that your advisor gives you a good grade.

Comment: @MalJA I added now a version of the left picture that is IMHO more in the spirit of Ti*k*Z. Does that solve your original question? No. However, I already mentioned that your pictures are too crowded IMHO opinion. As you can see, this code has zero (!) hardcoded coordinates. Everything is consistent with the theory of general relativity, i.e. all elements are placed relative to each other. If you want to make adjustments, you only need to change one thing rather than many. Hope this will make you less angry.

Comment: `(ha) (Ha) (aha) (He)` sounds like a dialogue among thespians fighting each other.

Comment: Thanks, Marmot a lot for all your suggestions, help and criticisms. I always learn from YOU. I will do my best to improve my knowledge with TikZ and my technical skills. Your existence and other experts in such a platform facilitate people's life.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use the power of `TikZ` to place two figures side by side by side in a `scope` environment to shift the second to the right.

```
\end{scope}
%              \end{tikzpicture}
%              \hfil
%                \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\begin{scope}[xshift=6.8cm]
```

Then to place a legend in a Tikz `node`.

```
\node at (2,-.5) {Legend \#1};
```

### Update:

I didn't understand your request correctly, here is a correction that respects your margin. It is displayed thanks to the `showframe` package.
I had to reduce your figures by a factor of `0.8` so that they would contain in your line.

I modified the `clip` of your figure. geogebra did not minimize this `clip`.

```
         %\draw(-.6,-1) rectangle (6.3,5.5);
         \clip(-.6,-1) rectangle (6.3,5.5);
```

[image: legends]

I have not modified or simplified the rest of your code that was obviously generated with geogebra.

```
 \documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
              \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
               \usepackage{mathrsfs}
               \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
                \pagestyle{empty}

                 \begin{document}
                 \definecolor{xdxdff}{rgb}{0.49019607843137253,0.49019607843137253,1.}
               \definecolor{ududff}{rgb}{0.30196078431372547,0.30196078431372547,1.}
                \definecolor{zzttqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,0.}\definecolor{zzttqq}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,0.}

                  \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,scale=.8]
\begin{scope}
             %\draw(-.6,-1) rectangle (6.3,5.5);
             \clip(-.6,-1) rectangle (6.3,5.5);
             \fill[line width=0.8pt,color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (0.,5.) -- (1.24,5.) -- (1.2201234230270745,0.19579267785163076) -- (0.,0.2) -- cycle;
             \fill[line width=0.8pt,color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (4.64,5.) -- (5.8,5.) -- (5.8,0.18) -- (4.64015172233386,0.1839994768195382) -- cycle;
            \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,5.)-- (5.8,5.);
            \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,4.)-- (5.8,4.);
            \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,0.2)-- (5.8,0.18);
            \draw (0.2,0.3) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize L_{f}$};
            \draw (4.7,0.26) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize L_{a}=L_{e}$};
            \draw [line width=0.8pt] (4.64,5.)-- (4.64015172233386,0.1839994768195382);
             \draw [line width=0.8pt] (5.8,1.18)-- (0.,1.16);
           \draw [line width=0.8pt] (1.24,5.)-- (1.2201234230270745,0.19579267785163076);
            \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,5.)-- (0.,0.2);
            \draw [line width=0.8pt] (5.8,5.)-- (5.8,0.18);
             \draw (0.62,4.76) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize h$};
             \draw (4.7,4.76) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize ha$};
             \draw (2.4,5.16) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize \psi_{a}\vert_{_{_{H_{f}}}}   $};
             \draw [line width=1.2pt] (1.04,4.3)-- (4.42,4.28);
             \draw [line width=1.2pt] (5.5,4.2)-- (5.5,1.38);
            \draw (4.68,3.34) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize \phi_{a^{*}}\vert_{_{_{H_{a}}}}   $};
               \draw (2.3,2.84) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize \Psi   $};
              \draw (4.74,1.28) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize a^{*}ha$};
             \draw (0.06,5.18) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize H_{f}$};
            \draw (5.32,5.18) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize H_{a}$};
            \draw (5.26,0.86) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize H_{e}$};
            \draw (-0.72,1.08) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize R_{e}$};
            \draw [line width=0.8pt,dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (1.42,3.78)-- (4.42,1.36);
            \begin{scriptsize}
             \draw [fill=black,shift={(4.42,4.28)},rotate=270] (0,0) ++(0 pt,2.25pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,-3.375pt)--++(-3.8971143170299736pt,0 pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,3.375pt);
              \draw [fill=black,shift={(5.5,1.38)},rotate=180] (0,0) ++(0 pt,2.25pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,-3.375pt)--++(-3.8971143170299736pt,0 pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,3.375pt);
                \draw [fill=ududff] (1.04,4.3) circle (1.0pt);
               \draw [fill=ududff] (5.5,4.2) circle (1.0pt);
                \draw [fill=black,shift={(4.42,1.36)}] (0,0) ++(0 pt,2.25pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,-3.375pt)--++(-3.8971143170299736pt,0 pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,3.375pt);
             \draw [fill=xdxdff] (-5.8,5.) circle (2.5pt);
              \draw[color=xdxdff] (-4.18,6.47) node {$G'$};
              \end{scriptsize}
              \node at (2,-.5) {Legend \#1};
\end{scope}
%              \end{tikzpicture}
%              \hfil
%                \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\begin{scope}[xshift=6.8cm]
             %\draw(-.6,-1) rectangle (6.3,5.5);
             \clip(-.6,-1) rectangle (6.3,5.5);
               \fill[line width=2.pt,color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (0.,5.) -- (5.8,5.) -- (5.8,4.) -- (0.,4.) -- cycle;
              \fill[line width=2.pt,color=zzttqq,fill=zzttqq,fill opacity=0.10000000149011612] (0.,1.16) -- (5.8,1.18) -- (5.8,0.18) -- (0.,0.2) -- cycle;
              \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,5.)-- (5.8,5.);
              \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,4.)-- (5.8,4.);
              \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,0.2)-- (5.8,0.18);
              \draw (-0.66,5.02) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize R_{f}$};
               \draw (4.7,0.26) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize L_{a}=L_{e}$};
               \draw [line width=0.8pt] (4.64,5.)-- (4.64015172233386,0.1839994768195382);
                \draw [line width=0.8pt] (5.8,1.18)-- (0.,1.16);
                \draw [line width=0.8pt] (1.24,5.)-- (1.2201234230270745,0.19579267785163076);
               \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,5.)-- (0.,0.2);
               \draw [line width=0.8pt] (5.8,5.)-- (5.8,0.18);
               \draw (2.2,2.76) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize \Psi^{-1}   $};
               \draw (0.06,5.18) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize H_{f}$};
               \draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (4.74,0.44)-- (1.42,0.44);
                \draw [line width=0.8pt,dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (0.18,0.66)-- (0.2,3.8);
                \draw (2.66,1.3) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize \psi_{a^{*}}\vert_{_{_{H_{e}}}}   $};
                \draw (5.32,1.32) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize H_{e}$};
                \draw (0.38,3.32) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize \phi_{a}\vert_{_{_{H_{a^{*}}}}}   $};
                \draw (-0.72,1.08) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize R_{a^{*}}$};
               \draw (4.86,0.96) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize g$};
                \draw [line width=0.8pt,dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (1.42,3.78)-- (4.42,1.36);
                 \draw (0.4,0.94) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize ga^{*}$};
                   \draw (0.28,4.72) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize aga^{*}$};
                   \draw (0.62,1.38) node[anchor=north west] {$\footnotesize H_{a^{*}}$};
               \begin{scriptsize}
                \draw [fill=black] (4.74,0.44) circle (1.0pt);
                \draw [fill=black,shift={(1.42,0.44)},rotate=90] (0,0) ++(0 pt,2.25pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,-3.375pt)--++(-3.8971143170299736pt,0 pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,3.375pt);
                 \draw [fill=black] (0.18,0.66) circle (1.0pt);
                  \draw [fill=black,shift={(0.2,3.8)}] (0,0) ++(0 pt,2.25pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,-3.375pt)--++(-3.8971143170299736pt,0 pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,3.375pt);
                  \draw [fill=black,shift={(1.42,3.78)},rotate=180] (0,0) ++(0 pt,2.25pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,-3.375pt)--++(-3.8971143170299736pt,0 pt) -- ++(1.9485571585149868pt,3.375pt);
                   \end{scriptsize}
                   \node at (2,-.5) {Legend \#2};
\end{scope}

                    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, AndreC for your suggestion and help I always learn from such a webpage.